# I get HTTP 503 error when trying to download images from a server which is protected by ClourFlare

Tags: java, image, cloudflare

I wrote a Java code which crawls pages of a CloudFlare protected site. I bypassed the protection by waiting 6 seconds after getting the page source. I saved the image URLs into a List and at the end of my code, I'm trying to download the images.

Here's the code:

```
images.forEach((baseUrl) -> {
        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(baseUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
            File outputfile = new File("e:/saved.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error during image (" + baseUrl + ") download: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error during image download: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I know that all files will be saved to saved.jpg to I will need a solution there. But what is more important now is the error message:

Error during image download: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://xxxxxxxxx.com/fold/original_263320.jpg?1592415320

I found on the internet that maybe this happens because of Cloudflare. How can I get the images?

Comment: Does the 503 code only occur when you crawl the image in your code? Or does it also happen when you try to visit the url for the image in your browser?

Comment: I can see it in my browser. But I forgot to tell you that I'm using a VPN for grabbing the data piaces. But still, the code is working, except the images. But when I'm running the code without VPN, I'm getting back an HTTP 403 error, when I'm using my VPN, I'm getting HTTP 503 error.

Comment: So... the 403 error could possibly be solved by adding  `connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");`

I guess that the server you are trying to reach is looking for an Agent identifier and because you haven't set one, you are forbidden to access the image.

Comment: Thank you. After I solved the access problem of Java to local disk, it is working without VPN. But I have some fears if it is a good idea to crawl few thousand images from a website with VPN, how can I solve this problem?